# Conditionally select column values in dplyr and then changing the datatype

Tags: r, dplyr

I have following dataframe in R

```
   Lead.Stage       Number.of.Followup.Calls
1 Not Interested             Select
2  Unreachable                  ""
3   Qualified                   1
4  Unreachable                  2
5   Qualified                   2
6   Junk Lead                Select
```

Number.of.Followup.Calls is of character type. I want to perform a groupby on Lead.Stage to calculate average no of follow up calls for that Lead.Stage

In dplyr I am filtering out `Select and empty String` and then converting digits to numeric one. I am using following code in r,but it does not seem to work.

```
train %>% 
  group_by(Lead.Stage)  %>%
  filter((Number.of.Followup.Calls == "" | Number.of.Followup.Calls ==  
  "Select")) %>% 
  mutate_each_(funs(as.numeric), Number.of.Followup.Calls)  %>% 
  summarise(Total = mean(Number.of.Followup.Calls))
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have a `factor` column for the second one?  If so, do `train %>% group_by(Lead.Stage) %>% filter(as.character(Number.of.Followup.Calls)==`

Comment: This filter keeps those Numbers of Follow Ups that are not numbers. You probably want the filter the other way around, so that only valid numbers pass. Insert a Negation `!` in the filter condition. If that does not work, lease provide example data to make your code reproducible.

Comment: @akrun No both are character type.

Comment: @Bernhard When I use negation in filter it gives me following error `  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"` This is how i am using it `filter(!(Number.of.Followup.Calls == "") | (Number.of.Followup.Calls == "Select"))`

Comment: Try `filter(Number.of.Followup.Calls != '' & Number.of.Followup.Calls != 'Select')`

Comment: We can use `data.table`.  `library(data.table);setDT(train)[!Number.of.Followup.Calls %in% c("", "Select"), Lead.Stage]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to do this with `%in%`

```
train %>% 
    group_by(Lead.Stage)  %>%
    filter(!Number.of.Followup.Calls %in% c("", "Select")) %>%
    summarise(Total = mean(as.numeric(Number.of.Followup.Calls)))
#   Lead.Stage Total
#       <chr> <dbl>
#1   Qualified   1.5
#2 Unreachable   2.0
```

---

Or otherwise, we don't need to do all the `filter` and other stuff, as converting to `as.numeric` automatically changes all the non-numeric elements to `NA` and then just do `mean(., na.rm = TRUE)`

```
train %>% 
    group_by(Lead.Stage)  %>%
    summarise(Total = mean(as.numeric(Number.of.Followup.Calls), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    na.omit()
#    Lead.Stage Total
#        <chr> <dbl>
# 1   Qualified   1.5
#2 Unreachable   2.0
#Warning messages:
#1: In mean(as.numeric(c("", "2")), na.rm = TRUE) :
# NAs introduced by coercion
```

The `warning message` is just a friendly reminder about converting the `non-numeric` elements to `NA`.